# Passing object from View to Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, controller

so my intention is to make a button that allow a user to add an item to his Cart, in the db.savechanges method it catch these exceptions :

Property: Item_Name Error: The Item_Name field is required.
 iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Property: Item_Description Error: 
 The Item_Description field is required. s

i checked from my db and every single item has all their properties filled up, since i am new to asp.net i am surely missing something obvious that is messing with my data.

this is the view(trying to pass the item object in actionlink

```
      @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (index > 6)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        var newrow = 0;

        if (index == 0)
        {
            newrow = 1;
        }

        if (newrow == 1)
        {
            index++;
            <div class="product-one">
                <div class="col-md-2 product-left">
                    <div class="p-one simpleCart_shelfItem jwe">
                        <a href="single.html">
                            <!-- go to product single view page-->
                            @{ if (item.Image.Image1 != null)
                                {
                                    string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image.Image1);
                                    string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
                                    <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
                                }
                            }
                            @Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddToCart", "Carts", new { itemdata = item }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
                        </a>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

this is the controller:

```
   public ActionResult AddToCart(Item item)
    {
        //var query = from itemsel in db.Items where item.Item_ID == item.Item_ID select item;
        var newcart = new Cart();
        newcart.Account_ID = 1;
        newcart.Cart_ID = 3;
        newcart.Item_ID = item.Item_ID;
        newcart.Item = item;
        var itemsgroup = db.Items;
        try
        {
            db.Carts.Add(newcart);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
         catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                            validationError.PropertyName,
                                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(itemsgroup.ToList());
    }
```

and this is the cart model:

```
 public partial class Cart
     {
        public int Cart_ID { get; set; }
        public int Account_ID { get; set; }
        public int Item_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
     }
  }
```

p.s i know my view is tricky but i am desperate to finish this project very soon, any suggestion for a better way of doing it would be welcomed

Comment: Which in the view is the object item? I can't understand that chunk of code. Or more exactly how the Item class looks like and what you need to send from the view to the controller?

Comment: i will edit the question, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are missing too many pieces, I could only point you to right direction.

Download the sample source code of **[Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book By Adam Freeman](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-mvc-5)**.

Extract Chapter 9 - SportsStore, and look at those two files-

**SportsStore.WebUI > Views > Product > [List.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-mvc-5/blob/master/Chapter%2009/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/Views/Product/List.cshtml)**

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Products) {
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}
```

**SportsStore.WebUI > Views > Shared > ProductSummary.cshtml**

Notice that it uses **BeginForm** to add individual item to shopping cart.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart")) {
    <div class="pull-right">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i solved my problem by passing the object id using TempData but this is far from good practice, due to assignment deadline i can't even think of best practice i just need to make it all work, but thanks i need this kind of resource :)